# TableView return repeated items every time app runs

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, realm

So, I am using Realm database and my TableView returns new set of data every time. So, for the first time, I got 3 items. The second time it's 6 items and etc.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var ModelName = [String]()
var Power = [String]()



func addPanel () {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let allPanels = realm.objects(Panel)
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(Panel(model: "Hyundai", power: 260))
        realm.add(Panel(model: "Honda", power: 420))
        realm.add(Panel(model: "Siemens", power: 280))
    }

    tableView.reloadData()


    for i in allPanels {
        ModelName.append(i.model)
        Power.append("\(i.power)")
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPanel()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return ModelName.count //changed from 3
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    //connect NameLabel cell to the name of Model and PowerLabel cell to the power 

    cell.NameLabel.text = ModelName[indexPath.row]
    cell.PowerLabel.text = Power [indexPath.row]



    return cell
}
```

If I limit my the number of rows to 3, the app works.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return ModelName.count //changed from 3
}
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because every time this controller is loaded, you add three objects to Realm. Since by default, update is false, you will be adding three new objects to Realm every time. If you change update to true, then it should use the primary key of the object and "update" these objects every view controller load.

```
public func add(_ object: Object, update: Bool = false)
```